# Load function called twice on loading WSAPI store in Rally SDK

Tags: rally

I am querying testcases and creating the store. I have a listener which has a load function. This load function is called twice. I can't seem to find the reason in the docs or anywhere on the web.

```
           listeners: {
                        load: function(store, data, success) {

                            this._onTestsLoaded(store, data);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
```

ontestsLoaded is another function.

Comment: Please provide more context, i.e. show the full config object for your Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store. Both the config and the full constructor for the TestCase store would also be helpful. Note that if you have autoLoad: true set in the store config, don't also call the load() method on the store or it will call load twice, similar to what you describe.

Comment: If I turn off the autoLoad , the store doen't load at all. How do I call a function onLoad without this load() method?

Comment: if you're not manually calling load() and you're receiving double load events that seems like a bug.  can you please post a bit more of your code so we can try to repro?

Comment: Ohh I found the issue..It was a stupid mistake..I was calling the function with the listener twice. Once on ready and once on change. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

here is mine 5 cents:

Your call:

```
   listeners: {
                load: this._onTestsLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
```

Your function:

```
_onTestsLoaded: function(store, data) {
    // do your stuff with data here
}
```